# Web alternative to MS Access

Tags: ms-access, web, visual-studio-lightswitch

I've seen multiple questions, along the same lines as this, however they're usually quite outdated, and/or not answered well if at all.

I've been experimenting with Visual Studio LightSwitch, but it has many problems, and is also considered dead by much of the community now, just as Access is.

There isn't really much to say, so my question is, IS there a decent alternative? Or do I just have to make do with Access?

Answer (score 1):

As you've already seen, there is no straight route. What to choose usually ends up in "that depends", and so it does - the only common factor is, that you are facing a total rewrite.

However, one way to cut it really short for a setup with few and known remote users, is to use Remote Desktop and Terminal Services of a Windows Server.

LightSwitch is not officially dead. I have done a few applications with it, and it is fun because it is so much different from Access with its firm screen design. Originally, it required Silverlight which now is dead, but today you use HTML5 at the client, so it won't get outdated right away.

Answer (score 0):

From Access to Web the usual path is PHP.